# Scala XML "\" and "\\" not working after including Scala Parser Combinator with JavaTokenParser

Tags: xml, scala, parser-combinators

The Scala program that was working perfectly was broken after I have included trait with Scala Parser Combinator (`JavaTokenParser`) as below

```
 trait QueryFragmentsParser  extends JavaTokenParsers  {
  .......
 }

 object QueryTranslator extends QueryFragmentsParser {
 .....
 .....
 val rootNodeID = (xml \ "@nodeid").toString()
 }
```

Error Message in Eclipse:

> value \ is not a member of QueryTranslator.Elem    QueryTranslator.scala

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

I have used the following scala xml libraries.

```
import scala.xml.XML 
import scala.xml.Node 
import scala.xml.Text 
import scala.xml.Elem 
import scala.xml.Attribute 
import scala.xml.Null 
import scala.xml.transform._ 
import scala.xml.pull._ 
import scala.annotation.tailrec 
import scala.xml.UnprefixedAttribute.
```

Comment: I have used the following scala xml libraries. `import scala.xml.XML
import scala.xml.Node
import scala.xml.Text
import scala.xml.Elem
import scala.xml.Attribute
import scala.xml.Null
import scala.xml.transform._
import scala.xml.pull._
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.xml.UnprefixedAttribute`. And QueryTranslator.Elem is inherited from one of them I guess..

Comment: I guess "\" character is defined in both scala.xml.Elem and JavaTokenParsers that causes this issue.. I dont know how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 2):

The `Parsers` trait defines a type named `Elem`. Your `object QueryTranslator` inherits from `Parser`, so it also has a type `QueryTranslator.Elem`. Since you also inherit from `RegexParser` and `JavaTokenParsers`, `QueryTranslator.Elem` is an alias for `Char` as that's how those traits define that type. Apparently `xml` is of type `QueryTranslator.Elem`. So when you do `xml \ ...` that's an error because `xml` is a `Char` and there is no `\` operator for `Char`s.

So the problem is that `xml` is of type `QueryTranslator.Elem` when you want it to be of type `scala.xml.Elem`. Presumably this is the case because you wrote `xml : Elem` somewhere inside `QueryTranslator`. Since `Elem` will always refer to `QueryTranslator.Elem` inside `QueryTranslator`, you'll either have to import `scala.xml.Elem` using an alias or refer to it using its (perhaps partially) qualified name. So two workable solutions would be:

```
import scala.xml.{Elem => XElem}
// ...
def foo(xml: XElem) = ...
```

or

```
import scala.xml
// ...
def foo(doc: xml.Elem) = ...
```

Comment: I went with the first option and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much